# Commenting in SCSS without transpiling

Tags: sass, styling, transpiler

I started using SCSS only recently and was wondering if there is a way to place comments that are not being translated into the CSS file. I use the SASS transpiler as plugin in PHPStorm.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look there :
http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#comments

```
/*  My comment here */
```

will be compiled.

```
// My comment here
```

won't.